# How Node.js https post JSON field looks in jquery format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

My question is Node uses request.write to send JSON post request and jquery's AJAX uses the 'data' field. Do I understand it right?

Here my node.js

```
const apiToken = "eae5819bd5e14803a1abff8141c36ee6";
const contentJSON = JSON.stringify({
  'contestId': "0ac3ac99-0509-456a-8ff6-9f193048c4f3",
  'contesttype': "OverUnder",
  'direction': "moon",
  'wager': "0.001"
});

const https = require('https');
const options = {
    hostname: 'beta.hxro.io',
    port: 443,
    path: '/hxroapi/api/ContestEntry/add-contest-entry',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'agh383j89dh93ij9',
        }
}

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
    res.on('data', (d) => {
        console.log(JSON.parse(d));
    });
});

req.on('error', (error) => {
    console.error(error);
});

req.write(contentJSON);
req.end();
```

This is what I think in jQuery it will look like:

```
contentJSON = {
  contestId: contestId,
  userId: "AB",
  contesttype: "OverUnder",
  direction: "moon",
  wager: "0.00005"
};
console.log(contentJSON);
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "https://beta.hxro.io/hxroapi/api/ContestEntry/add-contest-entry",
  data: JSON.stringify(contentJSON),
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": "sa77euhe83ji40ie"
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  },
  failure: function(errMsg) {
    alert(errMsg);
  }
});
```

Node's one works but not the jquery. JS solutions are welcome.

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: I'm getting nothing in console for jquery

Comment: It could be CORS issue.  There should be some error in console.

Comment: But im sure the post has not been a success

Comment: do you mean i can use the api through node but not jq?

Comment: Yes, There are some restriction in browser, you cannot make a cross site request without enabling it in the backend server.

Comment: Any workaround? I converted a lot other 'get' requests till stuck here.

Comment: No, there is no workaround, if you have access to the api server then you have to enable the cros there.